# Return data from database in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have problem with returning data from database in smarty.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM komunikaty";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = array();
while ($rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
$smarty->assign('komunikaty', $rows);
```

and its not working...

```
{foreach from=$rows item=komunikaty}
         {$komunikaty.title}
{/foreach}
```

why this doesn't work? im new in smarty...

Comment: This code is unfortunately riddled with logic errors. You are assigning the associative array to $rows as an array (when in fact, you most likely want $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result). In addition to that, you are doing nothing within the while loop as you open and close it within the same line "{}". It is also worth noting that mysql_* has been deprecated for some time in favour of mysqli and more predominantly, PDO.

Comment: Which Smarty version are you using and are you sure that `$rows` contain any data before the assignment? As a side note, you should **not** use the old `mysql` extension.

Answer (score 0):

you Assign  komunikaty

```
$smarty->assign('komunikaty', $rows);
```

in your tpl use

```
{foreach $komunikaty as $item}
       {$item.title}
{/foreach}
```

this work correctly.

Comment: syntax error: invalid attribute name: '$komunikaty'